# Cached memory on unix machine continuously grows

Tags: unix, ubuntu, memory

On my Ubuntu 12 vps I am running a full bitcoin node.  When I first start this up it uses around 700mb of memory.  If I come back 24 hours later (free -m) will look something like this:

```
  total used free shared buffers cached

  4002  3881 120    0      32     2635
```

-/+ buffers/cache: 1214  2787

Swap:  255   0   255

But then if I clear "cached" using

echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

and then do free -m again:

```
 total used free shared buffers cached

 4002  1260 2742   0      1      88
```

-/+ buffers/cache: 1170 2831

Swap: 255   0   255

Can see the cached column clears and I have way more free memory than it looked like before.

I have some questions:

what is this cached number?
    my guess is it's files being cached for quicker access to the disk?

is it okay to let it grow and use all my free memory?

will other processes that need memory be able to evict the cached memory?

if not, should I routinely clear it using the echo3 command I showed earlier?

Comment: worth looking at http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: wow that is exactly my questions. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Linux tries to utilize the system resources more efficiently. Linux caches the data to reduce the no. of io operations thereby speeding up the system. The metadata about the data is stored in buffers and the actual data will be stored in the cache.

When you clear the cache the processes using cache will lose the data so you have to run 
    `sync`
 before clearing the cache so that the system will copy the data to secondary storage which reduces the errors.